# Receiving JavaScript window.postMessages in an Android WebView

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview

I have an Android application in which I'm loading a webpage in an `WebView` which sends a JavaScript `window.postMessage` event upon success/failure of an action.

On web, this is usually handled with something like this (in the parent page):

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(event) {
    // handle event
}
```

How would this kind of thing be handled with an Android WebView? That is, once this event is sent, I'd like my application to dismiss the WebView and handle it natively. Is there a way to listen to these messages with a WebView?

Comment: you don't need the `JSON.parse` part, and in fact it doesn't make sense that a string would have an `.origin` property... if you are doing extra encoding and send()ing actual JSON proper in a string, you still want to parse `event.data` instead of the whole event object.